# Closing A Specific WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I open a form in the following way:

```
FormSomething FormSomething = new FormSomething(SomethingId);
FormSomething.Show();
```

In my code, there is a possibility for many FormSomething's to be open at once.  How do I close a specific instance of a FormSomething?

Each instance of FormSomething has an Id associated with it.

Edit: I guess what I'm really trying to get at is being able to *externally* close a specific instance of FormSomething.

I'd really appreciate any tips! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Close method on the Form class that you could call.

Sounds like you just need to keep a list of the forms that you have open so that you can refer to them later:

```
    List<FormSomthing> _SomethingForms = new List<FormSomething>();

    void DisplaySomething()
    {
        FormSomething FormSomething = new FormSomething(SomethingId);
        _SomethingForms.Add(FormSomething);
        FormSomething.Show();
    }

    void CloseThatSucka(int somethingId)
    {
        // You might as well use a Dictionary instead of a List (unless you just hate dictionaries...)
        var form = _SomethingForms.Find(frm => frm.SomethingId == somethingId);
        if(form != null)
        {
            form.Close();
            _SomethingForms.Remove(form);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A minor point, the `Remove` would be better off inside the `if (form != null)` test.

Comment: Hey guys, ok, I built it all up, but it's crashing on form.Close(); 
I'll get the error message after pulling my code out of a try, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FormSomething' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep track of them.  A dictionary is the natural collection object.  For example:

```
    Dictionary<int, Form2> instances = new Dictionary<int, Form2>();

    public void OpenForm(int id) {
        if (instances.ContainsKey(id)) {
            var frm = instances[id];
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            frm.Focus();
        }
        else {
            var frm = new Form2(id);
            instances.Add(id, frm);
            frm.FormClosed += delegate { instances.Remove(id); };
            frm.Show();
        }
    }
```